# Agregar iconos dependiendo de la propiedad del GeoJson

Tags: javascript, map, openlayers

estoy haciendo un mapa y necesito hacer que los vectores tengan un ícono diferente dependiendo el nombre de las estaciones de mi GeoJson en openlayers.
He llegado a obtener el nombre  de la estación con un "for" pero cada vez que intento enviar el resultado obtenido al src del vector me toma solo el último valor.
Intenté hacerlo con un If y con un switch pero el resultado es el mismo

```
let startDatajson = (new ol.format.GeoJSON({
        dataProjection : 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection:  'EPSG:3857',
    })).readFeatures(startJson);
     let stationStartSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: startDatajson       
    });
        var onLoadSrc;
        var getLoadStation = startDatajson.length;
          for(i=0;i<getLoadStation;i++){
            var getStation = startDatajson[i].get("Station");
                 if(getStation == "NNAA"){
                    onLoadSrc="assets/img/alert-smaller.png";
                }else{
                    onLoadSrc="assets/img/blue-triangle.png";
                } 
                /* switch(getStation){
                    case "NNAA": onLoadSrc="assets/img/alert-smaller.png";
                    break;
                    case "LIM027": onLoadSrc="assets/img/blue-triangle.png";
                    break;
                } */
                console.log(getStation);
                console.log(onLoadSrc);
         }

         
        /* creating image as style */ 
        var startIconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                anchor: [0.5,0.5],
                size: [28,19],
                offset: [1,1],
                scale: 1,
                src: onLoadSrc,       
            })
            
        });  
        /* creating vector and adding image on style created before */
        startStationsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: stationStartSource,
        visible:true,
        title:"ultimasEstaciones",
        style: startIconStyle,
                       
    });  
    map.addLayer(startStationsLayer);
```

Como muestro en consola el resultado si se muestra cada vez que el ¨for" se incrementa, pero cuando lo paso al "src" solo toma el la ultima ruta
[image: resultado en consola]

Comment: Solo cambia la declaración de variable en el ciclo para limitar su ámbito: `for(let i = 0; i < getLoadStation; i++) {`

Comment: te refieres a getLoadStation cambiar el var por un let o const? Hice eso y me resulto lo mismo

Comment: Una de las cosas que pasa es que `onLoadSrc` esta afuera del `for`, pero se actualiza dentro del for. Cuando el for termine, `onLoadSrc`  va a tener el último valor.

Comment: En realidad, primero estaba creado dentro del for y el ir. Es decir if{.... var onLoadSrc.....  }ese {var onLoadSrc...) Pero el resultado era el mismo